# batch-size for efficient eager loading of collection object graph in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I want to eager load a collection of objects efficiently.  The following code sample shows what I'm doing now.  But the c.CommunicationMethods & c.Roles objects are loaded 1 Sql statement at a time.  I saw references to the bag & batch-size... can someone provide sample mapping file references?  Is that my best option?  Can I keep my loop here & batch my sql statements?

Both CommunicationMethods & Roles are defined as many-to-one in the Contacts mapping file.

```
NHibernateUtil.Initialize(entity.Collection1);
NHibernateUtil.Initialize(entity.Collection2);

NHibernateUtil.Initialize(entity.Contacts);
foreach (var c in entity.Contacts)
{
NHibernateUtil.Initialize(c.CommunicationMethods);
NHibernateUtil.Initialize(c.Roles);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use prefetch paths while querying?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you mean this: .SetFetchMode("CommunicationMethods", FetchMode.Eager) ?  If not, can you point me to an example?

Answer (score 4):

instead of Initialize you could specify which collections to initialise while querying and with multiqueries you could hold the cartesian product small.

```
// load all collection1 into cache
session.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .Where(filter)
    .Fetch(e => e.Collection1).Eager
    .Future();

// load all collection2 into cache
session.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .Where(filter)
    .Fetch(e => e.Collection2).Eager
    .Future();

var results = session.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .Where(filter)
    .Fetch(e => e.Contacts).Eager
    .Fetch(e => e.Contacts.CommunicationMethods).Eager
    .Fetch(e => e.Contacts.Roles).Eager
    .List();

// results contain all entities with initialised collection1, collection2, contacts, contact.role, contact.CommunicationMethod
```